# Материалы для веб-разработки на python

Tags: python, django, backend

вкатываюсь в веб разработку на Python, и столкнулся с следующей проблемой. Буквально вчера закончил работу над веб-приложением на фреймворке aiohttp по туториалу из видеокурса, и пока смотрел и повторял код из курса все было плюс минус понятно, но когда самостоятельно взялся за задачу по добавлению некоторого функционала в уже существующий проект столкнулся с полным непониманием что вообще происходит. Примерно такая же ситуация с Django, по туториалам все получается, но когда сталкиваюсь с более серьезным решения найти не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть есть какая-то теория о том, как вообще устроена бэкэнд разработка, где есть подробная информация про используемые абстрактные понятия, например,  модели вьюхи и т.п., и почему это все устроено так , а не иначе. Просто очень большое желание вникнуть в суть и научится грамотно оперировать различными абстракциями для решения задач. К слову синтаксис языка достаточно хорошо знаю, с теорией http запросов знаком, простые sql на PgSQL написать могу и примерно представляю что такое бизнес-логика. Но вот общую картину разработки в целом не могу составить. Если кто-то может поделитесь, пожалуйста, знанием как прийти к пониманию

Answer (score 1):

Заходите на этот сайт, и берите все что хотите себе. Если кратко, то это дорожная карта по развитию в backend development. Английский знать не обязательно, достаточно воспользоваться переводчиком хром или любого другого браузера

[Backend Developer RoadMap](https://roadmap.sh/backend)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень полезная информация